# Kubernetes ingress-nginx basic-auth and jwt

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, basic-authentication, ingress-nginx

I have an issue with ingress-nginx that I cannot solve.

I have an ingress which allow connexion by IP whitelist or basic auth configured with the following annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "61.56.175.124/32"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: "basic-auth"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/satisfy: "any"
```

This work well on the ingress side. As behind it is a staging environment, I need such configuration to give access to everyone that need to work on it and no one else.

The website behind use a jwt token to handle user connection. This nginx configuration break the website connexion as the Authorisation header is filtred out by nginx.

How can I use both a basic auth and a JWT ?